# how to completely blank video output on boot (no kernel logging, grub output, etc.)

Tags: debian, boot, grub, init, kernel-parameters

So, this is an inversion of the classic question: "Why is my terminal blank on boot?" -- How do I make my terminal blank on boot?

I'm creating a Debian Wheezy system with GRUB as the boot loader that will output video over nodm ("no display manager" -- requires no user login).  I don't want users to see any boot information on their video screen at startup.

At the display manager level I use nodm and that seems to work great.

At the GRUB level I'm using these params in /etc/default/grub (and then running update-grub):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU=true
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=
#GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="silent splash loglevel=3 console=tty2 earlyprintk=tty2"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

And for inittab I use a custom program:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat -
```

/etc/inittab:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 -i -w -n -l /usr/bin/nothing tty1
```

Then finally I'm tweaking the BIOS settings as much as it will allow me.

The log output I still see appears to be GRUB related, it's roughly as follows:

```
"Booting GNU/Linux .... " <-- I think this is the GRUB option at index 0 that is loading

"Decompressing the kernel"
"Booting the kernel" <-- not sure if these are GRUB or Kernel related?
```

Does anyone have some advice on purging these final bits of text?

--Update--:

This link indicates those final lines may require a kernel patch to remove:

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-975550.html

Comment: Easy quick hack: put the console on a serial port. You won't see anything on the video output device!

Comment: Where would that be done?  The output messages I'm seeing currently seem to be GRUB related.  I already set the kernel to go to tty2 using GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.

Comment: That is usually done with these 3 lines in `/etc/default/grub`: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nofb console=ttyS0,115200"` and `GRUB_TERMINAL=serial` and `GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"`.

Comment: Hmm that looked very promising but I'm still seeing the "Welcome to GRUB...Booting...Decompressing...Booting" output.  I will keep investigating to see if it's something in how I'm supplying the params.

Answer (score 1):

The GRUB banner is printed before configuration files are read, so the only way to get rid of them is patching the source or the binaries. There is [prior art](http://rabexc.org/posts/grub-shush) in this field, though, if you really mean it. Syslinux behaves the same in this respect. The boot loader banner is often used as a "progress bar": different parts of it are printed by different stages of the bootstrap.

On the other hand, most kernel log messages (everything besides serious errors) are suppressed by the `quiet` kernel parameter. Try that instead of `silent`.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like unfortunately there would be two source level patches required: one for GRUB and one for the kernel.

Comment: I don't think you need to patch the kernel. The `quiet` parameter did the trick for me.

Comment: I still see it "early console in decompress kernel"..., etc.  I'm running kernel version 3.16.   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 nofb"